# Microsoft Graph: Selective consent to application-level permissions

Tags: scope, permissions, microsoft-graph-api

So i have an AAD app that requests a number of permissions. I have delegate permissions and application permission.
I want all my customer to use the same app but then admins should be able decide which permissions they would prefer to allow.

So for instance I have Calendar.Read and Calendar.ReadWrite application-permission requests on my app. Some admins will only like to consent to Calendar.Read.
Is this even possible? As per [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent)

I tried having the customer admin consent to only Calendar.Read using

```
// Line breaks are for legibility only.
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/v2.0/adminconsent?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&state=12345
&redirect_uri=http://localhost/myapp/permissions
&scope= https://graph.microsoft.com/calendars.read
```

I can see in the customers enterprise applications that that Calendar.Read is permitted under `Admin consent` tab. Unfortunately its registered of type `Delegate`. I need the permission to be of type `Application`. How do I do this?

As expected when i try to get client credentials token, the token has no permissions so i cannot use the token to make any calls. What am i missing here?

Answer (score -1):

There are settings which admins can choose for enabling the admin consent workflow and choose reviewers:

[Admin Consent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMCZb.png.)

Please refer this [DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-admin-consent-workflow#enable-the-admin-consent-workflow)

For configuring the  user content please refer this [DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-user-consent?tabs=azure-portal#prerequisites)

Comment: This does not address my problem. What i want is for admins to be able to give my App partial consent for Application-Level permissions.